# How to train a neural network autoencoder (Keras) on Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, keras, pyspark, autoencoder, systemml

I created a very large **Spark Dataframe** with PySpark on my cluster, which is too big to fit into memory. I also have an **autoencoder model with Keras**, which takes in a Pandas dataframe (in-memory object).

What is the best way to bring those two worlds together?

I found some libraries that provide Deep Learning on Spark, but is seems only for [hyper parameter tuning](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/25/deep-learning-with-apache-spark-and-tensorflow.html) or wont support autoencoders like [Apache SystemML](https://systemml.apache.org/)

I am surely not the first one to train a NN on Spark Dataframes. I have a conceptual gap here, please help!

Comment: Got a similar question here. Have you got any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Pandas DF in Spark are in-memory object and training won't be distributed. For distributed training you have to rely on Spark DF and some specific third party packages to handle the distributed training :

You can find the information here :
https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/train-model/distributed-training/index.html